# C++ String Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to create a data tree from strings that are expanded by at least 1 letter that is reachable from the current start word. My starting word in this case Dog and the ending word i want for this case would be maybe cat. I have to check that the word from the dictionary is the same size and not already in the vector words and also that if it only 1 letter difference.
Below I have tried already implementing this type of thinking but I think I'm missing something crucial. That I need help looking for or maybe add to my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cctype>       // For the letter checking functions
#include <fstream>      // For file input
#include <vector>       // For the use of vectors
#include <cstdlib>      // For exit and abs
using namespace std;



int main(){

vector<string> dictionary;
vector<string> words;
string startWord = "dog";
string endWord = "cat";

dictionary.push_back("dog");
dictionary.push_back("bog");
dictionary.push_back("cog");
dictionary.push_back("fog");
dictionary.push_back("cat");


 words.push_back(startWord);
                int counter = 0;
                int countline = 0;
                while( counter < words.size() ){
                    cout << words[counter] << ":   ";
                    for(int j = 0; j < dictionary.size(); j++){
                        for(int l = 0; l < startWord.size(); l++){
                            for(int k = 0; k < dictionary.at(j).length(); k++){
                                if(dictionary.at(j)[k] == startWord[k]){
                                    counter++;
                                    if(counter == 1){
                                        countline++;
                                        words.push_back(dictionary[l]);
                                        cout << words[l]<< endl;
                                        cout << " The succeded word is "<< words[l] << endl;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } // ends while
```

I only provided some of the words in my Dictionary but in reality I have a lot in my actual code that are of length 3 and are in the actual dictionary(Webster). I only added those few for the sake of being general to what i need.

Sample Output i am trying to achieve should be something like this ....

```
0. dog:   1:bog 2:cog 3:fog 4:gog 5:hog 6:jog 7:log 8:mog 9:nog 10:rog 11:sog 12:tog 13:vog 14:wog 15:dag 16:deg 17:dig 18:dug 19:dob 20
:doc 21:dod 22:doe 23:dol 24:dom 25:don 26:dop 27:dor 28:dos 29:dot 30:dow
1. bog:   31:bag 32:beg 33:big 34:bug 35:boa 36:bob 37:bod 38:bom 39:bon 40:boo 41:bop 42:bor 43:bos 44:bot 45:bow 46:boy
2. cog:   47:cag 48:cig 49:cob 50:cod 51:coe 52:col 53:con 54:coo 55:cop 56:cor 57:cos 58:cot 59:cow 60:cox 61:coy 62:coz
3. fog:   63:fag 64:fig 65:fob 66:fod 67:foe 68:fon 69:foo 70:fop 71:for 72:fot 73:fou 74:fow 75:fox 76:foy
4. gog:   77:gag 78:gig 79:goa 80:gob 81:god 82:goi 83:gol 84:gon 85:goo 86:gor 87:gos 88:got 89:goy
5. hog:   90:hag 91:hug 92:hob 93:hod 94:hoe 95:hoi 96:hon 97:hop 98:hot 99:how 100:hox 101:hoy
6. jog:   102:jag 103:jig 104:jug 105:job 106:joe 107:jon 108:jos 109:jot 110:jow 111:joy
7. log:   112:lag 113:leg 114:lug 115:loa 116:lob 117:lod 118:lof 119:loo 120:lop 121:lot 122:lou 123:low 124:lox 125:loy
8. mog:   126:mag 127:meg 128:mig 129:mug 130:mob 131:mod 132:moe 133:moi 134:mon 135:moo 136:mop 137:mor 138:mot 139:mou 140:mow 141:mo
y
9. nog:   142:nag 143:nig 144:noa 145:nob 146:nod 147:non 148:nor 149:not 150:nou 151:now 152:noy
10. rog:   153:rag 154:reg 155:rig 156:rug 157:rob 158:roc 159:rod 160:roe 161:roi 162:rok 163:ron 164:rot 165:row 166:rox 167:roy
11. sog:   168:sag 169:seg 170:sig 171:sob 172:soc 173:sod 174:soe 175:soh 176:sok 177:sol 178:son 179:sop 180:sot 181:sou 182:sov 183:s
ow 184:soy
12. tog:   185:tag 186:teg 187:tig 188:tug 189:tyg 190:toa 191:tod 192:toe 193:toi 194:tol 195:tom 196:ton 197:too 198:top 199:tor 200:t
ot 201:tou 202:tow 203:tox 204:toy
13. vog:   205:vag 206:vug 207:vod 208:voe 209:vol 210:vow
14. wog:   211:wag 212:wig 213:wob 214:wod 215:woe 216:won 217:woo 218:wop 219:wot 220:wow 221:woy
15. dag:   222:zag 223:dab 224:dad 225:dae 226:dah 227:dak 228:dal 229:dam 230:dan 231:dao 232:dap 233:dar 234:das 235:daw 236:day
16. deg:   237:keg 238:peg 239:deb 240:dee 241:del 242:den 243:dev 244:dew 245:dey
17. dig:   246:pig 247:zig 248:dib 249:did 250:die 251:dim 252:din 253:dip 254:dis 255:dit 256:div
18. dug:   257:pug 258:dub 259:dud 260:due 261:dum 262:dun 263:duo 264:dup 265:dux
19. dob:   266:kob 267:pob
20. doc:
21. dod:   268:pod
22. doe:   269:poe 270:yoe 271:dye
23. dol:   272:kol 273:pol
24. dom:   274:pom 275:yom
25. don:   276:eon 277:ion 278:kon 279:pon 280:yon
26. dop:   281:kop 282:pop
27. dor:   283:kor 284:yor
28. dos:   285:kos
29. dot:   286:pot 287:yot
30. dow:   288:pow 289:yow
31. bag:   290:baa 291:bab 292:bac 293:bad 294:bae 295:bah 296:bal 297:bam 298:ban 299:bap 300:bar 301:bas 302:bat 303:baw 304:bay
32. beg:   305:bea 306:bed 307:bee 308:bel 309:ben 310:ber 311:bes 312:bet 313:bey
33. big:   314:bib 315:bid 316:bim 317:bin 318:bis 319:bit 320:biz
34. bug:   321:bub 322:bud 323:bum 324:bun 325:bur 326:bus 327:but 328:buy
35. boa:   329:koa 330:poa 331:zoa 332:bra
36. bob:
37. bod:
38. bom:
39. bon:
40. boo:   333:zoo 334:blo
41. bop:
42. bor:
43. bos:
44. bot:
45. bow:
46. boy:   335:poy 336:yoy
47. cag:   337:cab 338:cad 339:cal 340:cam 341:can 342:cap 343:car 344:cat
```

Comment: 6 nested control structures, 4 of which are loops. Yes, we are down the rabbit hole.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What does it mean "are expanded by at least 1 letter". You say tree, but I see only vectors. I have no idea what your example is supposed to illustrate. For an example show the complete input and the output.

Comment: Sorry about that wording is off. So the program I'm trying to create is one that changes one word to another. For instance I want to change the word "dog" into "cat" . I then want to display the words that could be expanded from dog by only switching 1 letter. So from dog i can get cog, bog, fog, cog, jog...etc. All of those words being real words that are the same length and are only changed once. @bolov

Comment: so you have: a dictionary of real words. A start word and an end word. You start from the startWord and through successful transformation you want to end on endWord. A successful transformation from one word to another is to change just 1 letter and the resulting word must be in the dictionary. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Let me update the output desired so you can see. Also i have to take into count the index of each element.@bolov

Comment: that is not what your output shows...

Comment: You need to rethink your approach. The performance of this code is going to massively degrade as the size of your data set increases. Investigate the use of hashtables, sets and avoid nesting your loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid an infinite loop, you need to remember words that you have already seen. In the following code example, I use an `unordered_set<string>` for that (add `#include <unordered_set>`.

Then, the code could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> dictionary;
    vector<pair<string, int>> words; //stores (word, predecessor)
    string startWord = "dog";
    string endWord = "cat";

    unordered_set<string> seenWords;

    dictionary.push_back("dog");
    dictionary.push_back("bog");
    dictionary.push_back("cog");
    dictionary.push_back("fog");
    dictionary.push_back("cat");
    dictionary.push_back("bag");
    dictionary.push_back("beg");
    dictionary.push_back("bet");
    dictionary.push_back("bat");


    words.emplace_back(startWord, -1);
    seenWords.insert(startWord);

    bool found = false;

    //Try all new words as reference words
    for(int i = 0; i < words.size() && !found; ++i) {       
        //we look for words that we can generate from words[i]
        cout << i << " " << words[i].first << ":   ";

        //try all the words from the dictionary
        for (int j = 0; j < dictionary.size(); j++) {
            string& candidate = dictionary[j];
            //check if candidate can be generated from reference

            //count the different characters
            int differentCharacters = 0;
            for (int pos = 0; pos < words[i].first.size(); ++pos)
            {
                if (candidate[pos] != words[i].first[pos])
                    ++differentCharacters;
            }
            if (differentCharacters == 1 && seenWords.find(candidate) == seenWords.end()) {
                //yes, we can generate this candidate from word[i] and we haven't seen the word before
                cout << "(" << words.size() << ")" << candidate << " ";                         

                words.emplace_back(candidate, i);
                seenWords.insert(candidate);

                if (candidate == endWord) {
                    found = true;
                    cout << "Found endword";
                    break;
                }
            }           
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    if (found) {
        //traverse the word path from the end word back to the start word
        int i = words.size() - 1;
        stack<string> wordPath;
        while (i != -1) {
            //push the current word onto a stack
            wordPath.push(words[i].first);
            //go to the previous word
            i = words[i].second;
        }

        //now retrieve the words from the stack and print them in reverse order
        cout << "Word path:" << endl;
        while (!wordPath.empty()) {
            cout << wordPath.top() << " ";
            wordPath.pop();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which gives us:

```
0 dog:   (1)bog (2)cog (3)fog
1 bog:   (4)bag (5)beg
2 cog:
3 fog:
4 bag:   (6)bat
5 beg:   (7)bet
6 bat:   (8)cat Found endword
Word path:
dog bog bag bat cat
```

A live version can be found [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Bkuabx3_r)

Comment: Since you are interested only in words with a single difference, as soon as you have 2 differences, no need to continue counting characters. For longer words, this could save a lot of time.

Comment: if i want to check if the new word equals end word could i just add another if loop after the one you left off?

Comment: An `if` statement is not a loop. But, yes. Simply add `if(candidate == endWord) cout << "Found endword";` or similar.

Comment: Is there a way i can display the sequence based on the indexes to how i got from one word to another. So for instance if dog was the start word at index 0. And dog i got cog which is at index 2 and son on so forth until i get cat?

Comment: Store for every word the original word from which you came, i.e. `words` does not only contain a single `string`, but might be, e.g. `pair<string, int>`. Then, when you found your word, walk back this path through other words.

Comment: So for the code you provided.  Do you suggest I change words to pair <into,string> words ?

Comment: Edited the answer to include that part.

Comment: Do i need to include an extra #include other then stack? i get this error message........redefinition of 'words' with a different type: 'vector<pair<std::__cxx11::string, int> >' (aka 'vector<pair<basic_string<char>, int> >') vs 'vector<pair<std::__cxx11::string, int> > &' (aka 'vector<pair<basic_string<char>, int> > &')

Comment: That seems to be a copy/paste problem where you had a definition of `words` previously. I added a link to an online compiler, where you can see the results.

Comment: Got it. it was my compiler. So you have have it said to be traverse but it still starts printing at dog. How do i change it too start printing from cat to dog? and there respected index as well

Comment: If you want the reverse direction, then you don't need the stack. Instead of pushing onto the stack, simply print the word.

Comment: @NicoSchertler How can i also include the index of the words and also get them to go backwards so start from cat and end with dog? ive been messing with the code but i cant get.